# Flutter How To Sort Documents In Collection With Field Which Numbers Each Document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My question is how can we sort the documents in a collection, when each document has a field called `"Index"`, which goes from 1 to 10. I thought that the `orderBy("Index", descending: false)` should sort the documents in the collection going from 1 to 10 in the ascending order. Here is my code, and when I am calling orderBy(), the order of showing of documents in the Cloud Firestore is incorrect, and doesnt show the documents, in any order at all, neither descending or ascending... Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it!

```
if (petAge >= 42 && petAge <= 56) {
        await petRecordPath.add({
          'Completed': false,
          'Start Due Date': startDateMultiBooster,
          'End Due Date': endDateMultiBooster,
          'Display Range': displayMessageMultiBooster,
          'Importance': 'Vital',
          'Vaccination': 'Puppy Multi Vaccine (DHPP)',
          'Index': 1,
        }).then((value) async {
          await petRecordPath.add({
            'Completed': false,
            'Start Due Date': startDateMultiBooster,
            'End Due Date': endDateMultiBooster,
            'Display Range': displayMessageMultiBooster,
            'Importance': 'Recommended',
            'Vaccination': 'Leptospirosis Vaccine',
            'Index': 2,
          }).then((value) async {
            await petRecordPath.add({
              'Completed': false,
              'Start Due Date': startDateMultiBooster,
              'End Due Date': endDateMultiBooster,
              'Display Range': displayMessageMultiBooster,
              'Importance': 'Recommended',
              'Vaccination': 'Deworm 1',
              'Index': 3,
            });
          });
        }).whenComplete(() {
          petRecordPath.orderBy('Index', descending: false);
        });
      }
```

Here is how it looks in the Firebase console:

First Document:

[image]

Second Document:

[image]

Third Document:

[image]

Finally, with the build in sort feature from the console itself:

[image]

Comment: None of your code actually shows data from the documents yet. Can you edit your code to show how you read the documents, and (for example) print their Index values?

Comment: The Firestore console doesn't automatically order the documents. Only when you specify a sort order (like in your last screenshot) does it show the documents in that order. This is similar to how the API works: unless you specify a sort order when reading the documents, they will be retrieved in an undefined order.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, so could you let me know how I can read these documents in the correct way so that I know what it is being sorted correctly?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is this the correct function to specify the order in which the documents need to be added/ displayed on the console???

Comment: The `orderBy` looks fine at first glance. But your question is not showing how you actually read the data. If you edit your question to show the actual reading, and for example printing the Index field for each document, we have have a look at what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so you mean that, even though I call the orderBy() function in my code, it won't have any effect inside the firebase console, and only will be effective in calling the information back from my code itself using the orderBy function?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The console is not affected by `orderBy()` calls in your code. That would actually be quite bad, since it'd mean that any user could make API calls that change how your console displays the data.

Comment: Ok thanks, will update the question with the function to get the values and see if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firestore console doesn't automatically order the documents, and is not affect in any way by the `orderBy()` call that your code makes. In fact, that would mean that any user could make API calls that change how your console displays the data, which sounds like a bad idea.

Only when you specify a sort order in the console (like in your last screenshot) does it show the documents in that order.

This is similar to how the API works: unless you specify a sort order when reading the documents, they will be retrieved in an undefined order. And your `petRecordPath.orderBy('Index', descending: false)` would ensure that the documents are read by your code in the specified order.

Comment: Frank, thanks so much, now I have written a function which just prints the vaccination name for all the documents in the collection and have used the orderBy() function and it is working now, forgive me for my lack of understanding on this topic! Thanks so much again!